# EF lazy loading & fluent API creates additional field in table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, lazy-loading, fluent

Here is my code - first, `Attachment` class:

```
    public class Attachment{
    (...)
          public int UserId { get; set; }
          public virtual User Author { get; set; }

          public int? BasicMedicalDataId { get; set; }
          public virtual BasicMedicalData MedicalData { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is `BasicMedicalData` class:

```
    public class BasicMedicalData{
    (..)
          public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, `Attachment` can have optionally one connected `BasicMedicalData` object. 
`BasicMedicalData` can have a lot of `Attachments` objects.

With these lines in

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        (..)
        modelBuilder.Entity<Attachment>()
            .HasOptional(u => u.MedicalData)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.BasicMedicalDataId);


        modelBuilder.Entity<Attachment>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Author)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.UserId);

    }
```

It creates strange migration:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Attachments",
            c => new
                {
                    AttachmentId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    name = c.String(),
                    UserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    AddDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    BasicMedicalDataId = c.Int(),
                    del = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    BasicMedicalData_BasicMedicalDataId = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.AttachmentId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.PC_BasicMedicalData", t => t.BasicMedicalData_BasicMedicalDataId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.PC_BasicMedicalData", t => t.BasicMedicalDataId)
            .Index(t => t.UserId)
            .Index(t => t.BasicMedicalData_BasicMedicalDataId)
            .Index(t => t.BasicMedicalDataId);
    }
```

Problem is here - it creates additional field in database `BasicMedicalData_BasicMedicalDataId` and ignores in lazy loading with field `BasicMedicalDataId`.

When I put manually ID's in `BasicMedicalData_BasicMedicalDataId`, lazy loading with attachments works nice. But I cannot put here any value with code, because it is not a `Attachments` property..

How to resolve it? Why it creates 2x the same field with diffrent name? And why lazy loading with field `BasicMedicalDataId` does not working well?

Answer (score 0):

You have used the `WithMany()` overload that configures the relationship to be optional:many without a navigation property on the other side of the relationship - but you do have a navigation property on the other side of the relationship.

Try this:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Attachment>()
      //Attachment has an optional relationship with MedicalData
      .HasOptional(u => u.MedicalData)
       //It is many:optional with a navigation property named Attachments  
      .WithMany(d => d.Attachments)
      //The dependent's foreign key is BasicMedicalDataId    
      .HasForeignKey(u => u.BasicMedicalDataId);
```

Reference:
 [Optional WithMany Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679331%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)