# Why is this column getting generated in EF Code-First migrations?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a Mentorship entity, which has Student and Mentor as FKs:

```
    [Required]
    public int MentorId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Mentor { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Student { get; set; }
```

User model:

```
    public virtual ICollection<Mentorship> Mentorships { get; set; }
```

Fluent API:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Mentorship>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.Mentor)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.MentorId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Mentorship>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.Student)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.StudentId);
```

In my database, I see StudentId and MentorId columns which have been populated correctly, but I also see a User_UserId column that is not being used by anything.  What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the `WithMany()` overload that configures the relationship to be required:many without a navigation property on the other side of the relationship - but you do have a navigation property on the other side of the relationship.

Try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Mentorship>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.Mentor)
    .WithMany(d => d.Mentorships)
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.MentorId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Mentorship>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.Student)
    .WithMany(d => d.Mentorships)
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.StudentId);//oops! just realised that we just 
                                     //specified that Mentorships is using MentorId 
                                     //as the FK
```

References:

[Required WithMany Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696687%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

[Why do I get an extra foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19654478/150342)

**Edit**
Scratch that. Just realised you are trying to create two relationships with only one navigation property on the many side. You can't have a navigation property with 2 foreign keys. You need to introduce inheritance on the `User` side or remove the `Mentorships` navigation property from the `User` class or introduce separate `StudentMentorships` and `MentorMentorships` navigation properties

**Edit 2**
Finding a user once you've defined separate navigation properties

```
int userId = 123;//the one we want to find
var user = Users.Where(x => x.StudentMentorships.Any(s => s.StudentID == userId) 
                         || x.MentorMentorships.Any(s => s.MentorID == userId);
```

Comment: Using `WithMany()` without lambda parameter in one of the two mappings (maybe the second one) would work as well. It would mean that the `Mentorships` collection belongs to the first relationship only and the second relationship doesn't have an inverse collection.

Comment: @Slauma yes. So `StudentMentorships` or `MentorMentorships` on its own.

Comment: Wow, didn't think of that.  Thanks for the explanation.  I would like for <Student>.Mentorships to list all Mentorships where that Student's PK is listed in either of a Mentorship's FKs.  If you have time to demonstrate how this can be done, or any pointers, any help would be awesome.

Comment: @RobVious not sure I understand exactly what you mean but I've added how to interrogate separate navigation properties to get a user that is in one or the other

Comment: Thanks Colin - I see the edit.  This might be getting off-topic, but I'm interested in still using <User>.Mentorships to access both because throughout my code, that's how I get them now - maybe I can define something in the Getter of that navigation property to do both?

Comment: Yes, you could add a property like that. But then it is no longer a navigation property as such - so you can't use it in Linq-to-Entity queries. If you need it as a navigation property you may want to look at inheritance: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx but are you sure a Student is a User rather than Students having a UserProfile? No-one mentoring a student that isn't a user?

Comment: If I understand your question - a Student is a User, and a User has a List<Mentorship>.  Mentors are always Users as well.  I decided not to use UserProfiles and just put everything user-specific directly on the User model (though I'm beginning to regret that...)

Comment: More on whether inheritance is appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/53354/150342